# Connect to MySQL database on shared server issue

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two shared server accounts. They are identical, linux based servers.

I've set up an identical MySQL database (username, password, wildcard and user permissions) on both accounts that I want to access through my C# windows form application.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace SchoolGrades
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.AcceptButton = btnLogin;
        }


        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {    
            try
            {
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("SERVER=###;PORT=3306;DATABASE=###;UID=###;PASSWORD=###;");    
                con.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("Successful connection");    
            } 
          catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

        }
}
```

One of the connection strings establishes a connection, the other one outputs the following error:

> unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

I've read multiple SO posts with the same question, I've checked all options:

- Connection string;
- Firewall;
- User privilages.

Nothing seems to be the issue.

The only thing that pops to my mind is that I've setup SSL on the account that the connection cannot be established with.

Any ideas if this could be the problem? And if so, any hints how I can solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: what is the error message you are getting

Comment: Error: unable to connect to any of the specified mysql hosts

Comment: try exactly like this.. MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=###;Port=3306;Database=###;Uid=###;Pwd=###;"); i think its Pwd not the password.. may be workable to you

Comment: Can you share the connection  strings with sensitive information masked and tell what's the difference between them?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya the only difference is the server IP address.

Comment: Try running `telnet <serverip> 3306` from command prompt and see if it asked for mysql password

Comment: It states: Connecting To ###...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed

Comment: @did you try include property SslMode?

Comment: @user9405863 yes. I've tried different variations of ssl entries in the connection string. Including the one you mentioned below. But no result.

Comment: @Prometheus *"Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed"* I'm guessing the other server doesn't exhibit that behavior.  This suggests a connectivity problem, nothing to do with your code.

Answer (score 0):

try exactly like this..

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("Server=###;Port=3306;Database=###;Uid=###;Pwd=###;SslMode=Preferred;");`
```

include sslMode. hopefully that workable to you

Comment: I've double checked. It's not the issue unfortunately. :/

Comment: can you share full stack trace please

Comment: try to include SslMode=Preferred; along with connection string. use updated answer. i hope that works for you